# After upgrading to 16.10 no desktop enviroment anymore

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, graphics, 16.10

I upgraded to 16.10. I solved some graphics problems of nvidia driver because nothing was displayed on the desktop, but then I discoverd ( after fixing the problem ) that when I put the password in the password space the system doesn'work because no desktop enviroment is installed anymore.

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Exchange (ask ubuntu)!

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` (will reinstall desktop environment)
2. `sudo reboot` (reboot computer)

You may need to press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` to get to a terminal you can login to. (sorry mods if I got the formatting wrong).

Comment: Hi:) I did sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop and it displayed several sentences like: impossible to recover  http://archive.ubuntu.com/......

Comment: And "impossible to download some files" and suggested me to do "--fix-missing". Thank you:)

Comment: Apologies, run `sudo apt-get update` first before those.

Comment: It answered:  several sentences  like " impossible tosolve archive.ubuntu.com ". With several  "Err:4 http://archive.com/Ubuntu yakkety-security in release".  http"  or  "Err:1 http://archive.canonical.com/Ubuntu raring InRelwase".   At the end  "impossible to download some index files: they will be ignored or the old one will be use ".   Thank you :)

Comment: please visit http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46867/room-for-zor-and-markyisri

Comment: Hi:) I don't know how but I cannot use the chat room , it's written read-only.

Comment: @Zol of course, forgot you didn't have enough reputation. Send me an email at yisrimark@gmail.com and we'll go back and forth there, as this discussion is getting a bit long for comments.